# Pergunta "copiada" foi removida. O que fazer?

Tags: debate

Fiz uma pesquisa e achei [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234888/json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-j) que poderia me ajudar a resolver meu problema.
Porém ela está marcada como ***uma duplicata exata de*** outra.
Clicando na pergunta *"copiada"*, me deparo com o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo: pergunta *"copiada"* não existe e a pergunta *"cópia"* não está respondida. Em outras palavras, a pergunta não tem resposta e está fechada.

Devo **votar para que ela seja reaberta** ou **criar uma nova pergunta** com a minha dúvida?

Entendo que reabrir a pergunta seja justo com o autor, porém ela não iria para o início da lista de perguntas, tendo uma probabilidade menor de ser respondida.

Comment: eu acho que por questao de antiguidade, essa pergunta nem deveria ser mexida. Talvez voce possa recria-la e ela ser marcada com duplicata da sua, se for o caso.

Comment: A pergunta marcada como dup é exatamente a mesma (do mesmo autor) nesse você pode achar outra duplicada e adicionar pelo link do editar. Quanto a reabrir não é o caso.

Comment: @rray acho q ele nao tem esse privilegio ainda.

Comment: Para evitar problemas, como já explicado pelo @Renan na resposta, a duplicata também foi removida. Fique à vontade para postar a sua dúvida, caso ainda não o tenha feito que, pelo menos dessas duas, não tem mais como ser duplicata ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente nós tivemos um caso de um usuário que não soube usar o Stack Overflow. Ele abriu a mesma pergunta duas vezes - a pergunta mais velha foi marcada como duplicata da mais nova, e a mais nova foi removida automaticamente por ter diversos problemas.

Para piorar, a pergunta estava incompleta. O autor colocou código nela, mas não colocou o código todo - falta o JSON que provoca o erro. **Por este motivo, acho que reabrir esta pergunta não lhe ajudará**. A comunidade inclusive removeu a duplicata também, depois do seu alerta.

Sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta e adicionar o respectivo JSON, caso não ache nada similar no site.